# Failed to instantiate LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean due to error in @NameQueries?

Tags: java, jpa

I was trying make a NamedQuery in JPA. Unfortunately it was failed due to following reason:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/datasource.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2220)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:287)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: searchByUsername
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 20 more
```

This problem occurred whenever the web apps is loaded. I think the error is come from `@NamedQuery`, if I removed it, it'll working fine. Below is the code snippet on the POJO class.

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name="searchByUsername",
        query="select e from users u where u.username in (select a.username from authorities a where a.username = :username)"
    )
})
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Transient
    private String firstName;

    @Transient
    private String lastName;

    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="enabled")
    private Boolean enabled;

    @Transient
    private Role role;
}
```

This is the DAO class that responsible to make the call on the query:

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        try {
            User l = (User) emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery("searchByUsername", org.huahsin.WebEngineering.User.class).setParameter("username", username).getResultList();

               ...
            }
            ...
```

I wasn't sure whether I have miss configure anything in the Spring, I just put it here for your reference:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="abcd"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.huahsin" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the advantage of named queries: they fail fast. When the EntityManagerFactory is created, all named queries are checked, and if one of them is an invalid query, the creation fails.

That allows detecting errors in queries immediately, instead of waiting for their execution at runtime.

JPQL uses the name of entities and their fields. Never the name of tables and their columns. And you're selecting `e`, which doesn't correspond to any alias in your query.

The query should be:

```
select u from User u where u.username in (select a.username from Authority a where a.username = :username)
```

Comment: Just curious, in the my query I mention `users` which is the table name, whereas your query mention `User` which is an entity. Which one is correct?

Comment: Why don't you read my answer: *JPQL uses the name of entities and their fields. Never the name of tables and their columns.*

Comment: Sorry for bad, I should read your answer at least one thousand times before I ask for another.